# Is it possible to see what action was taken on a reported flag?

Tags: support

I've read several other questions where users asks why their flag was turned down for "this or that" reason. However I can't seem to locate this feature at all. Does it require any special priviligies or something similar? I try to do my best to flag questions that I don't think belong on StackOverflow, but I'm often left wondering if I flagged a question for the correct reason and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see what the status is on flags in your profile; click on the count next to 'helpful flags':

[image: helpful flags count is a link]

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Especially if you've been looking for love.